# convert .txt file data into json format

Tags: json

I have `user.txt` log file which have this data below and I want to convert it in json format.

```
{"user":"Demo Admin","user_id":"57c4718434243dc47d8b456c","org_id":"57c4718434243dc47d8b456b","superuser_id":null,"superuser_name":null,"application":"Trackier Webapp","method":"GET","ip":"43.249.54.66","domain":"demo.trackier.com","url":"https:\/\/demo.trackier.com\/admin.html","created":"2022-09-08 06:19:18","@timestamp":"2022-09-08T06:19:18Z"}
{"user":"Demo Admin","user_id":"57c4718434243dc47d8b456c","org_id":"57c4718434243dc47d8b456b","superuser_id":null,"superuser_name":null,"application":"Trackier Webapp","method":"GET","ip":"43.249.54.66","domain":"demo.trackier.com","url":"https:\/\/demo.trackier.com\/admin.html","created":"2022-09-08 06:19:35","@timestamp":"2022-09-08T06:19:35Z"}
```

Comment: but that's already a json format, isn't it? see in [https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

Comment: But that's already a json format. Maybe you want to cat the output of `user.txt` in json format.
If you want to achieve that, you can use the command jq, for example:
`jq < user.txt`

Comment: @αғsнιη More precisely, it is one json document per line, akin to https://jsonlines.org/.

Comment: Consider updating your question to show what the data should look like in the new format.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you want to convert that file with one json per line to one json array, you could do:

```
sed '1s/^/[/;$s/$/]/;$!s/$/,/' < file.multijson > file.json
```

Which inserts `[` at the start of the first line, `]` at the end of the last line, and `,` at the end of all but the last line.

If you have `jq`, you can also do:

```
jq -s < file.multijson > file.json
```

(add `-c` to get a compact form), but beware it may reformat numbers (like change 1e1 or 10.0000000000000001 to 10) or strings (like change `"\u00e9"` to `"é"`).